# install opencv on beagleboard black

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

So I recently brought a new beagleboard black and am looking forward to using it to do some image processing. I know this is probably a very bad question, but how to I go about setting my beagleboard to use opencv. According to researc, angstorm comes with opencv, but I can't find out how to actually use it. I could really use some help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.hackengineer.com/setting-up-your-beagleboard-with-angstrom-toolchain-and-opencv/) says

"Select Beagleboard

Select the Packages you want

OpenCV – Libraries will be readily available to include in your code

Toolchain – Ability to compile code natively on beagleboard
Build ( this step takes a while so be patient)"